# Converting human readable dates to milliseconds and back again without losing information

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I get human readable timestamps into my program. I want to store them in a database and work with them in different ways. I'd prefer to represent them as long ints since that is easier and more efficient, but it's also handy to be able to flip between what's handy for a machine to read and what's handy for a human.

I've hacked together the following test program including functions to convert to and from human readable timestamps to longs and back again.

```
// g++ -o timetest timetest.cpp -std=c++11

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>

long millis_from_date(const std::string& s)
{
  boost::posix_time::ptime pt;
  std::istringstream is(s);
  auto* f = new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%FZ");
  std::locale loc(std::locale(""), f);
  is.imbue(loc);
  is >> pt;
  boost::posix_time::ptime timet_start(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1));
  boost::posix_time::time_duration diff = pt - timet_start;
  return diff.total_milliseconds();
}

std::string date_from_millis(long ms)
{
  static const boost::posix_time::ptime epoch(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1));
  boost::posix_time::time_facet * facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ");
  std::ostringstream stream;
  stream.imbue(std::locale(stream.getloc(), facet));
  stream << epoch + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(ms);;
  return stream.str();
}

int main() 
{
  std::string time = "2016-04-14T07:47:50.120043Z";

  std::cout << "Initial input:           " << time << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  {
    long millis = millis_from_date(time);
    std::cout << "Initial input in millis: " << millis << std::endl;

    std::string newtime = date_from_millis(millis);
    std::cout << "Converted back to date:  " << newtime << std::endl;
  }

  {
    long millis = millis_from_date(time);
    std::cout << "Initial input in millis: " << millis << std::endl;

    std::string newtime = date_from_millis(millis);
    std::cout << "Converted back to date:  " << newtime << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the sample output.

```
Initial input:           2016-04-14T07:47:50.120043Z

Initial input in millis: 1460620070000
Converted back to date:  2016-04-14T07:47:50.000000Z
Initial input in millis: 1460620070000
Converted back to date:  2016-04-14T07:47:50.000000Z
```

As you can see, when converting to milliseconds, fractional second information is lost so what you get is seconds since begin of epoch with `000` tacked on the end. Thus when converting the resulting long back to a human readable timestamp the fractional second information is lost.

I've tried quite a few things by now and I can't figure out how the millis_from_date function should work without losing the fractional second info. Any ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove period prior to `%F` and it works. See example here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#time_input_facet_accessors

Note also that milliseconds are not enough to store the whole precision from your example `2016-04-14T07:47:50.120043Z`. Since you have 6 decimal digits, you would need microseconds.

Also note that there are a huge load of microseconds since 01-Jan-1970, so `long` is not enough. And it is not a good idea to use `long` anyway, since this type may have different size on different platforms. A better idea would be to use `uint64_t` for this purpose, that's what `boost` is using to store time durations. With help of 64 bits you will be able to store microseconds for another half of million of years or so.

Comment: Thank you Mikhail, I followed your advise and now everything works exactly as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone would like to work a problem like this using the newer C++11 `<chrono>` types, here is how you could do it using this [free open source library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) to help with the formatting and parsing of the fractional seconds:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

std::chrono::milliseconds
millis_from_date(const std::string& s)
{
  using namespace std::chrono;
  using sys_milliseconds = time_point<system_clock, milliseconds>;
  sys_milliseconds pt;
  std::istringstream is(s);
  date::parse(is, "%FT%TZ", pt);
  return pt.time_since_epoch();
}

std::string
date_from_millis(std::chrono::milliseconds ms)
{
  using namespace std::chrono;
  using sys_milliseconds = time_point<system_clock, milliseconds>;
  return date::format("%FT%TZ", sys_milliseconds{ms});
}

int
main() 
{
  std::string time = "2016-04-14T07:47:50.120043Z";

  std::cout << "Initial input:           " << time << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  {
    auto millis = millis_from_date(time);
    std::cout << "Initial input in millis: " << millis.count() << std::endl;

    std::string newtime = date_from_millis(millis);
    std::cout << "Converted back to date:  " << newtime << std::endl;
  }

  {
    auto millis = millis_from_date(time);
    std::cout << "Initial input in millis: " << millis.count() << std::endl;

    std::string newtime = date_from_millis(millis);
    std::cout << "Converted back to date:  " << newtime << std::endl;
  }
}
```

which outputs:

```
Initial input:           2016-04-14T07:47:50.120043Z

Initial input in millis: 1460620070120
Converted back to date:  2016-04-14T07:47:50.120Z
Initial input in millis: 1460620070120
Converted back to date:  2016-04-14T07:47:50.120Z
```

As noted in [Mikhail's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36825999/576911), if we truly want to be lossless here, we need to traffic in microseconds instead of milliseconds.  Here is how the above code would be changed to do that:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

std::chrono::microseconds
micros_from_date(const std::string& s)
{
  using namespace std::chrono;
  using sys_microseconds = time_point<system_clock, microseconds>;
  sys_microseconds pt;
  std::istringstream is(s);
  date::parse(is, "%FT%TZ", pt);
  return pt.time_since_epoch();
}

std::string
date_from_micros(std::chrono::microseconds ms)
{
  using namespace std::chrono;
  using sys_microseconds = time_point<system_clock, microseconds>;
  return date::format("%FT%TZ", sys_microseconds{ms});
}

int
main() 
{
  std::string time = "2016-04-14T07:47:50.120043Z";

  std::cout << "Initial input:           " << time << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  {
    auto micros = micros_from_date(time);
    std::cout << "Initial input in micros: " << micros.count() << std::endl;

    std::string newtime = date_from_micros(micros);
    std::cout << "Converted back to date:  " << newtime << std::endl;
  }

  {
    auto micros = micros_from_date(time);
    std::cout << "Initial input in micros: " << micros.count() << std::endl;

    std::string newtime = date_from_micros(micros);
    std::cout << "Converted back to date:  " << newtime << std::endl;
  }
}
```

which outputs:

```
Initial input:           2016-04-14T07:47:50.120043Z

Initial input in micros: 1460620070120043
Converted back to date:  2016-04-14T07:47:50.120043Z
Initial input in micros: 1460620070120043
Converted back to date:  2016-04-14T07:47:50.120043Z
```